# PHP gives different hex value than an online tool

Tags: php, steam

I'm connecting trough an API to Steam and get the SteamID from it for authentication purposes.

When I get my user_id from the API it gives me 76561198118533739 and when I check it on https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter, the proper hex value is the result (1100001096efa6b).

But, when I use the PHP function dechex it gives me the wrong value. How can I get the correct value to use?

Example:

```
<?php
echo dechex(76561198118533739); // 7fffffff
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP has no error reporting for this function, it should have given an error for integer overflow, but no such luck.. 7fffffff is the largest signed 32-bit integer, which is as close as this function will get on 32bit platforms. to properly convert this number to hex on a 32bit system, use a arbitrary precision library like bcmath or GMP to calculate the hex value, here's 1 of those posted in the comments by "joost at bingopaleis dot com"

```
function dec2hex($number)
{
    $hexvalues = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7',
               '8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F');
    $hexval = '';
     while($number != '0')
     {
        $hexval = $hexvalues[bcmod($number,'16')].$hexval;
        $number = bcdiv($number,'16',0);
    }
    return $hexval;
}
```

- it requires the bcmath extension to work.

also keep in mind that the number is too large to store as a number on 32bit systems, so you need to store it as a string.

```
dec2hex("76561198118533739"); // "1100001096efa6b"
```

if bcmath is not available, maybe it's time to upgrade your servers to 64bit?

Comment: Thanks @hanshenrik - as a charm! :)

Answer (score 2):

This differencie is because your php platform use 32 bit but the numer you test need 64 bit long (http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) - the binary online calculator give right answer.  You can check how much "bit" you have using `echo PHP_INT_SIZE*8;`

Comment: Is there a build in PHP function to get the same answer as the online tool?

Comment: I dont know but you can check how much "bit" you have using `echo PHP_INT_SIZE;` (4=32bit, 8=64bit)

Comment: The result of that is 4

Comment: try `echo PHP_INT_SIZE*8;`

Comment: @hanshenrik I update my answer using your very nice idea :)